# Rails on Heroku - DB edits via console not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have deployed my Rails application on Heroku. However, I cannot save DB edits via Heroku console.

If I want to update a model via the console I take the following steps -

```
rails console
@doc = Document.find_by_title('Test’)
@doc.status = 1
@doc.save*
```

However, in Heroku model saves do not work

```
heroku run rails c
@doc = Document.find_by_title('Test’)
@doc.status = 1
@doc.save
```

Console output is as follows

```
   (1.9ms)  BEGIN
   (1.9ms)  BEGIN
  Commontator::Thread Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "commontator_threads".* FROM "commontator_threads" WHERE "commontator_threads"."commontable_id" = $1 AND "commontator_threads"."commontable_type" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["commontable_id", 40], ["commontable_type", "Document"]]
  Commontator::Thread Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "commontator_threads".* FROM "commontator_threads" WHERE "commontator_threads"."commontable_id" = $1 AND "commontator_threads"."commontable_type" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["commontable_id", 40], ["commontable_type", "Document"]]
  Approval Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "approvals".* FROM "approvals" WHERE "approvals"."document_id" = $1  [["document_id", 40]]
  Approval Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "approvals".* FROM "approvals" WHERE "approvals"."document_id" = $1  [["document_id", 40]]
  Review Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."document_id" = $1  [["document_id", 40]]
  Review Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."document_id" = $1  [["document_id", 40]]
   (2.1ms)  ROLLBACK
   (2.1ms)  ROLLBACK
```

This is the same for any attribute I try to update.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you run `@doc.save`, isn't there any feedback on the console? If the update succeeded, there should be a `true` statement as a response. If there is a `false` statement as feedback, try running `@doc.save!`; that will show the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. It was being affected by validations, if you want to save and skip validation, then

```
@document.update_columns(status: 1)
```

or

```
@document.attribute['status'] = 1
@document.save
```

Both will skip validation.

Comment: You can also run `@document.valid? and @document.errors` to see why it was rolledback and not saved.  Probably would have pointed to the status issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

```
heroku run rails c
doc = Document.find_by_title("Test")
doc.status = 1
doc.save(validate: false)
```